# How can sync contacts and subscribers in Magento 2 with SendGrid? Any suggestions please

Tags: magento2, module, integration

I have a website on Magento 2 and I need sync all my contacts from Magento 2 to SendGrid. Track all new subscriptions, unsubscriptions from SendGrid and Magento. Also I need see and manage all Sendgrid marketing campaigns in my magento admin panel.

Maybe someone know any good solution for this? I found the official extension from SendGrid company for magento 2, but it's only with SMTP features :(

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty big question. There may be tools out there like Zapier that might help you bootstrap some kind of solution here. If you wanted to understand, technically, what you would need to build - check out this [extension for dotdigital Engagement Cloud](https://github.com/dotmailer/dotmailer-magento2-extension) or this [Mailchimp module](https://github.com/mailchimp/mc-magento2).

Both modules will have events that handle subscriptions, as well as cron jobs running to synchronise your subscribers, and some sort of UI in the Magento admin to view and monitor account activity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [Aitoc extension](https://www.aitoc.com/magento-2-sendgrid-integration.html). I didn't have a chance to try it myself but based on the description it should fit you.